# How to use multiline ellipses using CSS for all browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css

This is good for single line but I want it for multiline.

```css
div {
    display: block;
    height: 54px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-width: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    There are no questions currently added
    There are no questions currently added
    There are no questions currently added
</div>
```

Comment: what means multiline?

Comment: I thik you  have ti use jquery.

Comment: perhaps this is helps you http://codepen.io/martinwolf/pen/qlFdp

Comment: @AlexFilatov I think this works in Webkit only.

Answer (score 0):

you need to add spans like below

```
<div>
    <span>There are no questions currently added</span>
    <span>There are no questions currently added</span>
    <span>There are no questions currently added</span>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qstwa6aq/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can not do it with css alone. This is just not possible. You can add some HTML Tags, like @ozil suggested or you need to write your own JS solution. There might be some plugins around, but a simple solution would be, to cut the sting after x chars and add the three dots.